# How to get the value of an attribute inside an XML element in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

How do I get the value of an attribute inside an XML element?

For Example:
I want to get the value of attribute ***category***.

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) extension:

```
<?php
$xml = '<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
</bookstore>';
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $doc->book->attributes()->category; // cooking
echo $doc->book->title.PHP_EOL; // Everyday Italian
echo $doc->book->title->attributes()->lang.PHP_EOL; // en
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/HYH26)

Every element will be set as a property on the root object for you to access directly. In this particular case, you can use [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) to get the attributes of the `book` element.

You can see in the example that you can keep going through the levels in the same way: to get to the `lang` attribute in `book`, use `$doc->book->title->attributes()->lang`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("yourfile.xml");
echo $xml->book[0]['category'];
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides a `SimpleXML` class in the standard library that can be used for parsing XML files.

```
$data = <<<END
  <bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
END;


$xml = simplexml_load_string($data); 
$categoryAttributes = $xml->xpath('/bookstore/book/@category');
echo $categoryAttributes[0];
```